# Помогите записать формулу на ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер

Помогите записать формулу на ассемблере: z = 5*x*x + 12/y - 1

Answer (score 1):

Я бы записал это как-то вот так:

```
        xor ax,ax
        mov al, [x]
        mul ax
        mov bx, 5
        mul bx

        mov bx, ax
        mov ax, 12
        div [y]
        xor ah,ah

        add ax, bx
        sub ax, 1
```

Искомое значение будет в регистре `ax`.

Comment: Что-то меня настораживает `xor ah,ah` перед `add ax, bx` - разве ah не часть ax?

Comment: @Qwertiy, после деления мы получаем в `al` результат от деления, а в `ah` остаток. Принципиально, мы должны его тоже учитывать, но все будет зависеть от вводимых чисел.

Comment: А, понял. Интересная схема.

Comment: dec ax ;;;;;;;;